# Function of 令 in 你日日喺我耳邊唱歌令我好壓抑 (cantonese)

Tags: cantonese, nuance

> 你日日喺我耳邊唱歌令我好壓抑。

In this statement, what is the function of 令？ and why is it not 對？ I was kind of expecting to see a “對” somewhere here.

Comment: Hopefully this was not a comment on your singing

Comment: No, it's definitely about MY singing!

Comment: FYI 令 has the same function as standard Chinese (Mandarin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

令 has the meaning of "make"

> 你日日喺我耳邊唱歌[令]我好壓抑
>
> You sing by my ear side everyday [make] me very depress

對 means "to"

> 你日日喺我耳邊唱歌, [對]我是一种折磨
>
> You sing by my ear side everyday, [to] me is a kind of torture
>
> You sing by my ear side everyday is a kind of torture [to] me

Notice: "令"(make) is a verb. "對" (to) is a preposition

Answer (score 2):

> 你日日喺我耳邊唱歌 **令**我好壓抑。

壓抑 is an adjective, so you can't use 對 here.

令=make
令 is followed by an adjective, eg壓抑
.... makes me depressed

> 你日日喺我耳邊唱歌 **對**我 ☓好壓抑 ✓造成好大困擾

對=cause...to
對 is followed by a noun/phrase
... causes trouble to me

Answer (score 1):

令人 is a very common phrase.

令人：(used in conjunction with a verb) cause someone to (be, feel, etc)

令人不可思议
令人失望
令人出乎意料

你日日喺我耳邊唱歌[令]我好壓抑。
You singing in my ear every day is making me depressed.